# Selenium Issue with Exec?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, spyder

I am running a webscraper with selenium to get some data on the NBA.  I have urls to get to the websites for each of the 30 teams, but when I run the code it only gets through a few of the urls and then crashes with the errors below being shown:

```
#web scraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import os


class NBAScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        #part 1
        url = "https://www.nba.com/teams"
        HTML = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML.text, 'html.parser')
        text = str(soup.find_all("a", "Anchor_anchor__cSc3P TeamFigureLink_teamFigureLink__uqnNO"))
        ids = []
        for i in range(0, 30):
            hr = text.find("stats")
            ids.append(text[(hr+11):(hr+21)])
            text = text[(hr+22):]
        #part 2
        
        names = []
        for j in range(0, 30):    
            url2 = "https://www.nba.com/stats/team/"+str(ids[j])+"/advanced"
            HTML2 = requests.get(url2)
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(HTML2.text, 'html.parser')
        ##div class="TeamHeader_name__MmHlP
            name = str(soup2.find("div", "TeamHeader_name__MmHlP"))
            ni = name.find("div>")
            ni2 = name.find("<!")
            name1 = name[(ni+4):ni2]
            name = name[ni2:]
            ni3 = name.find("<div>")
            name = name[(ni3+5):]
            ni4 = name.find("</div>")
            name2 = name[:ni4]
            n = name1 + " " + name2
            names.append(n)
        ##tbody class="Crom_body__UYOcU"
        #part 3
        offrtg = []
        defrtg = []
        reb = []
        tov = []
        efg = []
        
        for k in range(0, 30):
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            url3 = "https://www.nba.com/stats/team/"+str(ids[k])+"/advanced"
            self.driver.get(url3)
            rndrhtml = self.driver.page_source
            self.driver.close()
            #self.driver.quit()
            soup3 = BeautifulSoup(rndrhtml, 'html.parser')
            ovrall = str(soup3.find("tbody", "Crom_body__UYOcU").find_all("td"))
            for d in range(0, 13):
                di = ovrall.find("<td>")
                ovrall = ovrall[(di+4):]
                #conditions
                if d == 2:
                    di2 = ovrall.find("</td>")
                    offrtg.append(float(ovrall[:di2]))
                elif d == 3:
                    di2 = ovrall.find("</td>")
                    defrtg.append(float(ovrall[:di2]))
                elif d == 10:
                    di2 = ovrall.find("</td>")
                    reb.append(float(ovrall[:di2]))
                elif d == 11:
                    di2 = ovrall.find("</td>")
                    tov.append(float(ovrall[:di2]))
                elif d == 12:
                    di2 = ovrall.find("</td>")
                    efg.append(float(ovrall[:di2]))
                    
                   
        #writing to excel
        os.remove(r"C:\Users\jackm\OneDrive\Desktop\NBA\NBASTATS.xlsx")
        d = {'Name': names, 'OFFRTG': offrtg, 'DEFRTG': defrtg, 'REB': reb, 
             'TOV': tov, 'EFG': efg}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
        df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\jackm\OneDrive\Desktop\NBA\NBASTATS.xlsx", sheet_name="STATS")

                
            
            
        
NBAScraper()
```

I tried to play around with the closing and quitting functions for the driver, or put the driver in a separate function and run it outside the class, but none of that worked.  I realized through some testing that even if it's not inside a loop, selenium will throw the error for a url but run it fine the second time.  I tried using implicit waits to solve this but to no avail.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\jackm\spyder\nba.py", line 104, in <module>
    NBAScraper()

  File "c:\users\jackm\spyder\nba.py", line 71, in __init__
    ovrall = str(soup3.find("tbody", "Crom_body__UYOcU").find_all("td"))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: Sometimes it is worth putting some delay between loops using something like `time.sleep(5)` or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but didn't seem to work.  Must be something with me reusing Chromedriver I'm trying to implement multiple instances to workaround.

Comment: Is the name `"Crom_body__UYOcU"` the same each time the page is loaded?